# How to change the landing page layout and content after somebody unsubscribes from a mailing

Tags: unsubscribe

is there a possibility to change the layout, font size, etc of the landing page after somebody clicks the unsubscribe token `{action.unsubscribeUrl}` ?

I've been looking for it but can't find.

Either via the back office or perhaps where the HTML is generated from the PHP?

We are using Drupal CMS

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Davey

Comment: Found the location myself.
templates\CRM\Mailing\Form\Unsubscribe.tpl